# Many to One microservice response not appear in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I make a microservice in controller my required values come from response but it not shown in postman but i post man i get the following response

> @RestController
> @RequestMapping("/rental")
> public class RentalController {
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> ```
>
> private RentalService rentalService;
>
> ```
> @GetMapping("/{id}")
> ```
>
> public ResponseEntity getRental(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
> Rental rl = rentalService.findRentalById(id);
> return ResponseEntity.ok(rl);
> }
>
> ```
> @GetMapping("/viewAll")
> ```
>
> public List getAllRental(){
> List ls = rentalService.viewAllRental();
> return ls;
> }
>
> }
>
> @Service
> public class RentalService {
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> ```
>
> private RentalRepository rentalRepository;
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> ```
>
> private RentalTypeRepository rentalTypeRepository;
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> ```
>
> private SizeTypeRepository sizeTypeRepository;
> @Autowired
> private SleepingArrangementRepository sleepingArrangementRepository;
>
> public Rental save(Rental rt) {
> return rentalRepository.save(rt);
> }
>
> public Rental findRentalById(Long id) {
> return rentalRepository.findAllByRentalId(id);
> }
>
> public List viewAllRental(){
> List lsRental= new ArrayList();
> lsRental = rentalRepository.findAll();
>
> return lsRental;
> }
>
> public List viewAllRentalType(){
> List lsRental= new ArrayList();
> lsRental = rentalTypeRepository.findAll();
> return lsRental;
> }
>
> public List viewAllSizeType(){
> List lsSizeType= new ArrayList();
> lsSizeType = sizeTypeRepository.findAll();
> return lsSizeType;
> }
>
> }
>
> @Repository
> public interface RentalRepository extends JpaRepository<Rental, Long> {
>
> public Rental findAllByRentalId(Long id);
>
> }
>
> @Entity
> @Getter
> @Setter
> @AllArgsConstructor
> @NoArgsConstructor
> @Table(name="rental",schema="bnb_pms")
> public class Rental {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
> @Column(name="RENTAL_ID")
> ```
>
> private long rentalId;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="RENTAL_NAME")
> ```
>
> private String rentalName;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="INTERNAL_NAME")
> ```
>
> private String internalName;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="DES")
> ```
>
> private String des;
>
> ```
> @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
> @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID")
> ```
>
> private RentalType rentalType;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="RENTAL_SIZE")
> ```
>
> private int rentalSize;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="GUEST_ACCOMODATE")
> ```
>
> private int guestAccomodate;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="TOTAL_UNITS")
> ```
>
> private int totalUnits;
>
> }
>
> @Entity
> @NoArgsConstructor
> @AllArgsConstructor
> @Table(name="rental_type",schema="bnb_pms")
> public class RentalType {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
> @Column(name="TYPE_ID")
> ```
>
> private long typeId;
>
> ```
> @Column(name="TYPE_NAME")
> ```
>
> private String typeName;
>
> }

In response i get the value of rental type as shown in figure,
[debugger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10mQ7.png)

but in postman rental type object is not shown. Postman response is as follow,

> {
> "rentalId": 453,
> "rentalName": "Ehsan ulhaq Darrr1659",
> "internalName": "Khadim Hussain Dar",
> "des": "ehsandar@gmail.com",
> "rentalType": {},
> "rentalSize": 2,
> "guestAccomodate": 4,
> "totalUnits": 3
> }

Comment: You should probably tag this as a JSON issue, as this has little to do with JPA and everything to do with how your java objects are being serialized into JSON (spring uses Jackson). Also notices the differences in your classes - Lombok is annoying, but one has getters and setters, the one that isn't working doesn't. Jackson uses property access unless you configure it to use fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has to do with your java objects serialization (via Jackson) to JSON, not JPA or the mappings. If you look at what is serialized:

```
"rentalType": {}
```

You can tell that there is an object being serialized, it just doesn't have any attributes or data. This is because Jackson will use property access by default.

If you check your entity definitions, the one that has data, Rental has:

```
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
```

While the RentalType class is just using:

```
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
```

If you add in the getters and setters, Jackson will be able to see the properties and include them in the object JSON.